# SOLR query runs OK only on 1 node out of the 3 nodes with SOLR installed

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Here's our problem. We're runnig DSE Enterprise 4.8 with the following configuration:

- 6 servers with Cassandra
- on 3 of them Spark is installes (DSE Analytics)
- on the orher 3 SOLR is installed (DSE Search)

We want to do "query stats" with SOLR on a table using and excluding certain filter queries.

When we try to execute a simple query like this:

```
/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fq={!tag=fq1}test:100&stats=true&stats.field={!ex=fq1}test&rows=1
```

it runs OK only on 1 node out of the 3 with SOLR installed.

For the other 2 nodes we get this exception:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":2},
  "error":{
    "msg":"undefined field: \"{!ex=fq1}test\"",
    "code":400},
  "params":"q=*:*&indent=true&stats=true&fq={!tag%3Dfq1}test:100&rows=1&wt=json&stats.field={!ex%3Dfq1}test"}
```

Could you help us identify the reason of the "undefined field" exception when using exluding filter queries inside the stats.field parameter.

Also it would help us to use only a subset of the stats functions ( for example only count ) :

stats.field={!count=true}test

But these types of parameters seem to be ignored  and the whole set of stats functions are computed...

Many Thanks

Comment: Does a normal `q=*:*` without filters etc work on all nodes for this core? If so then I would at a guess say it could be the fact that you need to run repair on this keyspace / table to first make sure you are consistent (if you haven't already)

Comment: The normal queries work on all nodes. The queries fail when trying to use any local parameters for stats.field.
The query works on a single node , but it is not always the same node. It seems to jump between 2 of the 3 nodes.

Comment: can you post your `schema.xml` and the table cql schema for this solr core please?

Comment: It seems our query works only on the master.When we restart the master node,the master changes.This explains why the query works on a different node. Still we don't understand why the query does not work on the slave nodes.

Comment: There's not really a concept of master in DSE for search.  Have you put the Spark and Search nodes in the same DC?  Are you using NTS or SimpleStrategy?

Comment: We have Spark and Search nodes in different DC.We use NTS.

Comment: We migrated to DSE 5 and now indeed there is no master in DSE Search. Now the query does not work on any node.

Comment: @georgeo Did the upgrade resolve your issue? If not, would you mind emailing Diego the start up account manager so we can get this resolved?